# Installed new bath faucet. No cold water comes out

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Hot water comes out fine, but not cold...none at all. It comes up to handle so I know there is water coming through cold line. But when I turn on cold water...nothing. Can the stem cartridge cause no water ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean by "it comes up to handle"?

Comment: Water is coming out hose and gets all the way to handle. Example. I take off handle (two handle faucet) and there is water in the place where spring and seal are. Water will come through but when I replace stem valve and handle it just doesn't work. I'm thinking it may be defective??

Comment: A picture of the faucet might help, but it sounds like your faucet is zonked.

Answer (score 1):

First verify that you have water coming through the cold line.  Make sure the shutoff value is turned off at the wall, disconnect the line from the faucet and put in a bucket.  Open the value and you should get a lot of water coming out at full pressure.

If that works, there is something wrong with your faucet.  Either something is blocking it or it's defective.  I once had this happen to me with a faucet from a big-box store.  I took everything apart to try to figure out what was wrong with it until I finally found that one of the valves was lacking a small grove that was the channel the water was supposed to come through.  It took me forever to notice it was different than the working side.  I went back and someone that worked there grabbed the part out of another box for me.

If this is a single handle faucet make sure you have installed the cartridge properly.  If it is not oriented right or the handle doesn't connect properly, you could have an issue like this.

Comment: Verified. I do think faucet is defective. I have taken both sides apart to compare and they appear to be exactly a like. So I'm seriously thinking it is defective/ Also when I took both handles off and valves out a lot of water came up through cold opening, so I know its getting water :) Thank you :)